# Why didn't more fire-heated homes have simple heat recovery systems?

Tags: heating, air-exchanger

Random question. This isn't something I'm going to build myself, and I've never lived in a cold climate, but I'm curious.

I read about "old drafty houses" in books, and part of what makes them drafty is that fireplaces create an air suction force.

Why didn't they just run a steel pipe from the outdoors, through the chimney (so it comes into contact with hot smoke), and then into the home, so that most of the draft air preferentially comes in that way?

This isn't quite the same as many fireplace heat exchangers that I've seen, in that it would actually take air from the outside, heat it, and then bring it into the living space. It seems much more efficient than cracking a window straight from the outdoors. And it would bring warm, fresh air into the room.

I'm sure some people have already done this or there's good reasons they haven't, but again, pure curiosity.

Comment: Free fuel(except for labour), no good choices for insulation(newspaper was used), no good sealing could be done with doors/windows/walls.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is more about economics, supply chain, and regulation than about DIY.    Also I think once you invent the heat exchanger, as you just did, it makes more sense to close the drafty cracks, use the heat exchanger to heat recirculated internal air, and burn cold air from outside rather than room air.   So it leads pretty quickly to a modern high efficiency furnace.  In reality that took about 80 years which isn't so bad for the home construction industry.

Comment: the steel pipe would have cost as much as the house probably

Comment: Preheated air would _also_ rise. Your premise is flawed. The fact is that chimney dynamics are more complicated than they seem, and such installations would be complex and expensive.

Comment: I think using exhaust air to condition combustion air is more a trick of the automotive industry than home.   Like, preheaters and turbochargers and that kind of thing.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based (speculative), theoretical, and too broad. There's no actual problem to solve here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a history-of-housing question rather than a home improvement question.

Answer (score 3):

In what time period? Remember that there's a reason cast-iron stoves with a flue pipe are called Franklin Stoves; before then you'd be looking at fireplaces.

Folks have commented in responding to another question that extracting more heat from the flue pipe than it already radiates would mean increasing creosote build-up and chimney-fire risk.

Beyond that: Things that are obvious in retrospect were rarely obvious before being done.

For what it's worth, I *have* seen a stone fireplace with ducts alongside the firebox and chimney to draw cold air from the room and use the heated stone to warm it. But that was relatively recent construction; I have no idea how far back such things might go. This secondary heat is also the advantage of fireplaces in the middle of the house rather than built into one end, though the risk of house fire was increased.

(I expect this question to be closed as off topic -- it's history of science/engineering rather than home improvement -- but I had an answer so I guv it.)

Comment: Oh, nice! Yes, the Franklin Stove seems to have efficiently implemented what I'm basically describing. But why is the input air from the floor, instead of directly from the outside air?

Comment: @Slothario  The houses were drafty and did not need it.  It has been only recently that houses were sealed enough to require extra outside air for burning.  It was not needed, so no one did it.  Even a 1980 house with a 1980 furnace usually did not have an outside air intake.

Answer (score 2):

> Why didn't they just run a steel pipe from the outdoors, through the chimney (so it comes into contact with hot smoke), and then into the home, so that most of the draft air preferentially comes in that way?

A concentric flue?  The problem with that is the intake air then cools off the exhaust air.  "How is that a problem? That sounds like a feature, only improves efficiency."  Traditional furnaces were *gravity furnaces* which means they rely on thermal convection to push the exhaust up the stack.  I.E. Hot air is thinner and lighter than cool air (PV=nRT) so it rises, and gravity pulls cold air into the combustion chamber. **If you cool off the hot air, the exhaust no longer rises**.  This "heat rises" scavenging (replacement of exhaust air) costs at least 20% efficiency, but it is a must-have in non-electric installations, such as pre-1900 homes.

The only way to beat that, and successfully use a concentric stack for the efficiency, is to have *actively blown* combustion air - which means you need electricity and reliable small motors.  This is Slim Potatohead's dilemma in this good video about choosing RV heaters. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3YHsW10pPU

> I read about "old drafty houses" in books, and part of what makes them drafty is that fireplaces create an air suction force.

That wasn't the reason, that was a convenient side-benefit.  The reason was they did not have the technological means to build a tight house where the tightness was maintainable. *But even more than that, the operative word there is **old**. You think of a house as "old" if it was built in 1880.  It probably wasn't drafty **in 1880**.  But by 1920, yeah, it's 40 years old and now it comes down to how well it is being maintained.  If that stock made it all the way to the 21st century, it's probably not well maintained at all, and is probably a rental.

Also, modern building materials do make sealing easier. Vinyl windows don't last like wood, but they do a better job sealing because vinyl doesn't swell from humidity/moisture.  A wood window or door needs to leave clearance for that.  That 1880 house in 1880 probably had brass side seals and top and bottom felts on the hung windows - those are long gone, and those helped a lot.